# fstream is not opening the files although everything looks fine

Tags: c++

```
void kick_start() {
    //function must run at start to create files
    fstream passkey;fstream database;
    //so that when password is changed its always overwritten
    passkey.open("key.txt", ios::out | ios::in);
    if (!passkey) {
        cout << "!!!ERROR OPENING CRITICAL SYSTEM FILES!!!\b" << endl;
        cout << "PROGRAM WILL NOW EXIT" << endl;
        Sleep(1500);
        exit(1);
    }
    database.open("Mainbase.txt", ios::app | ios::in);
    if (!database) {
        cout << "!!!ERROR OPENING CRITICAL SYSTEM FILES!!!\b" << endl;
        cout << "PROGRAM WILL NOW EXIT" << endl;
        Sleep(1500);
        exit(1);
    }
    int temp;
    temp = passkey.tellg();
    cout << temp;
}
int main() {
    //main function for the whole project
    start_animation anime;
    anime.animation();
    kick_start();
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

everything looks fine to me but still the program always exits with code 1 can't get why every time the function kick_start() is called it exits the program.

Comment: Try a little fishing. [Drop a `perror` into the fail case for the open calls and see what prints out.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/perror)

Comment: Whats the working directory of the application? Are you using VS?

Comment: Are you getting an error message?  Is passkey.open failing, or is database.open failing?  You should consider sharing that information.  And, as user4581301 suggests, print the system error message and see what's wrong.

Comment: You should write different error messages in two cases.

Comment: @Borgleader i am using visual studio and the .exe file is located at default  location

Comment: @Asad I figured as such. Visual studio by default sets the working directory to the *project directory* not the output directory. So your path isnt good (if the txt file is indeed in the same directory as the executable). Right click your project, go to Properties > Debugging and change *Working Directory* to `$(OutDir)` and try again.

Comment: @WilliamPursell i checked by commenting the passkey section it seems only passkey is failing but database is successfully created as it is not giving error message

Comment: @Borgleader i did that but it makes no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out your problem with a simple test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    {
        std::cout << "text2.txt: std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out" << std::endl;
        std::fstream foo("text2.txt", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << bool(foo) << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::cout << "text3.txt: std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::app" << std::endl;
        std::fstream foo("text3.txt", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::app);
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << bool(foo) << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::cout << "create text4.txt" << std::endl;
        std::fstream foo("text4.txt", std::ios_base::out);
    }

    {
        std::cout << "text4.txt: std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out" << std::endl;
        std::fstream foo("text4.txt", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << bool(foo) << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::cout << "text4.txt: std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::app" << std::endl;
        std::fstream foo("text4.txt", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::app);
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << bool(foo) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

With this I get the following output:

```
text2.txt: std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out
false
text3.txt: std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::app
true
create text4.txt
text4.txt: std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out
true
text4.txt: std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::app
true
```

And in the directory of my exe I have 2 files created (not 3): text3.txt and text4.txt. This behavior is explained by the table on [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open).

```
modestring  openmode & ~ate     Action if file already exists   Action if file does not exist
"a"         app, out|app        Append to file                  Create new
"r+"        out|in              Read from start                 Error
```

So essentially it's just a flag problem, either create the file up front or use the same flags on both (since as you said in the comments "i checked by commenting the passkey section it seems only passkey is failing but database is successfully created as it is not giving error message").

P.S: Not finding the file however could be caused by what I mentioned in the comments, i.e. your paths being relative to the .exe and the working directory being elsewhere (which is the default in Visual Studio)

Comment: using the same flags totally solved the problem thanks a lot